# Laravel Database - PDOException Integrity constraint violation Cannot delete or update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, migrate

I use `Laravel 5.2`.*
i have a problem error with database, currently database table :

```
  Schema::create('telepon', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('id_siswa')->unsigned()->primary('id_siswa');
        $table->string('nomor_telepon')->unique();

        $table->foreign('id_siswa')
                ->references('id')->on('siswa')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

and after migration i some problem the same with 'siswa' , in terminal :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                            SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or
>   upda     te a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop
>   table `siswa`)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

i have checked with

```
migrate:reset

migrate:refresh

migrate:rollback
```

with the same error

please help, thank you

Comment: try to delete all your tables manually and then `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally occurs when you connect tables using primary key.
As the error says cannot del or update parent table , that means you should remove dependencies from your mysql table or check your models if it has dependencies like has,have,in .
In lawman language you should delete child row first then only you can delete parent rows.
In your case telepon(id_siswa) and siswa(id) are connected.So first try to delete the coloumns in siswa then delete columns in telepon.